# Trust Percent Values in Flow sObject Variables Again (Critical Update)

Tags: critical-update

yesterday, I got an email to check my flows and processes concerning this critical update: http://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/summer16/release-notes/rn_forcecom_flow_percentage.htm

To check if everything works fine, I should activate this critical update,
but I can't find it.
Does it mean, that this update had been already be activated for my org, otherwise I should see it in Setup - "Critical Updates" should I?

Thank you!

Comment: You got this email yesterday? You should have been notified ~6 months ago. It's already live everywhere.

Comment: Yes, this is why I wonder how this could be... Okay, so never mind, thank you for your prompt answert!